# PHP cURL How get a page?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying get page by this code, but unsuccessfully.

After grab throw redirect (thing by JS).

```js
$url = 'https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/threats/malware-encyclopedia-description?Name=Trojan:Win32/Speesipro.A';
echo getPage($url);
function getPage($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

What should i do to get page by url without redirects?

Comment: Are you able to access that URL via browser ?

Comment: Of course. The page is displayed (by echo), but then redirected with "localdomain/en-us/wdsi/threats/threat-search?query=" url.

Comment: You try to fetch some object on the server side, that fails (according to your own statement, no details given from your side) and then you suggest it might be JS redirecting you? Em.....

Comment: i get http 200, i see the page content by echo (as real page) and after few seconds Denver shows "The requested URL /en-us/wdsi/threats/threat-search was not found on this server."

Comment: If you don't want redirects, you shouldn't set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` to `true`. Try setting it to `false`. Note that this affects the redirection by HTTP headers, not JS. But curl will not parse any JS anyway, so this cannot be the cause of redirection.

Comment: "after few seconds Denver shows ...": Who is Denver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid redirect, just add this line of code to the script to replace the last line

//return $result;

```
      return str_replace("https://c.s-microsoft.com/en-us/CMSScripts/script.jsx","",$result);
}
```

So, the javascript that gets loaded won't redirect the loaded page to the invalid URL.

Please check and let me know if this helps.

Comment: Best! That's what I need.

Comment: Glad that it helped!